# System.Collections.Generic lists in Python 'TypeError: type(s) expeected' error

Tags: python, list, typeerror, ironpython, python.net

I am trying to run the following piece of code:

```
import clr
import sys
#import System.Collections
clr.AddReference("System.Collections")
from System.Collections.Generic import List
from System import String

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, e=""):
        self.title = e


li = List[MyClass]()

list(li)
```

However, I am getting the error 'TypeError: type(s) expected' and cannot understand how to solve it.

This is related to System.Collections.Generic lists in Python

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Python.NET you can't use .NET lists to store Python objects in a strongly-typed way unless you do one of the following:

- derive your Python class from a .NET type

```py
class MyClass(System.Object):
   # without __namespace__ - regular Python type
  __namespace__ = "MyNamespace"
```

- use `List<System.Object>` or `List<Python.Runtime.PyObject>`
- have a `List<X>` with [a Python to .NET codec](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/wiki/Codecs:-customizing-object-marshalling-between-.NET-and-Python) for the .NET type `X`